# Pydev, shortcut for inserting if __name__ == '__main__' in code

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Is there shortcut or quicker way in Pydev to insert `if __name__ == '__main__'` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PyDev is based on Eclipse platform and all Eclipse tricks work there.

You can create your own shortcut templates for autocompletion.

E.g. if you type `main[ctrl+space]` it completes to `if __name__ == "__main__"`.

More information how to create custom Eclipse templates:

https://dzone.com/articles/effective-eclipse-custom-templ

Answer (score 1):

In **PyDev**, there is a *templates* section.  From the menu at the top of the Eclipse window, select: *Windows / Preferences / PyDev / Editor / Templates*

This will open a dialog box listing.

If you scroll down the list of templates, you will find one named
**main**. By selecting it, you can see what will be inserted.  If it's
not quite what you want, you can edit it.  You are also able to add
your own, with included variables.

In your source file, place the cursor where you want the `"if ..."` to go.  Begin to type `'main'`.  A popup menu should popup containing at least the entry: `"main - Main function pattern"`  Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the `if ...` will be entered in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

The same solution (as @Mikko Ohtamaa answered) is for the PyCharm IDE.

1. Type `main`
2. Click Tab

And the IDE will complete the line with `if __name__ == '__main__':`